# YUI :checked selector in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css-selectors, yui

I had a query written as:

```
Y.all('.myClass:checked');
```

It worked great in everything but IE (8). I can't seem to get `':checked'` to work at all with IE. Is it possible to query for only checked checkboxes like this and be compatible with IE?

Comment: What version of YUI are you using?

Comment: Sounds like they found and fixed the problem way back when: http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/ticket/2528895 could be something else going wrong. If no one gives you a good answer you might eventually want to file a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sounds like they found and fixed the problem way back when:
>   yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/ticket/2528895 could be something else
>   going wrong. If no one gives you a good answer you might eventually
>   want to file a bug report.

-TheZ (in comments of original question)

This is a bug in yui3 versions earlier than 3.2

Answer (score 6):

Have you included the selector-css3 module? otherwise I believe YUI will treat it like a normal query and that would be why you get it in modern browsers but not IE

```
YUI().use('node-base','selector-css3', function(Y){
    Y.all('.myClass:checked');//Should now work in all browsers
});
```

Remember to always declare your dependencies with YUI